# How manually validate a JWT Access Token emitted by Microsoft Login Provider?

Tags: api, security, access-token, asp.net-core-6.0

I got an Angular application that let's users login with a Microsoft and Google Account. Once the login step is over, I got an Access Token which is sent to the API for validation to secure the application. The API is a ASP.net Core 6 application.

I successfully validate an Access Token emitted by Google with the code below. But, I need to do the same with an Access Token emitted by Microsoft.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultSignOutScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MicrosoftTokenValidator()); // todo
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new GoogleTokenValidator());
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.AccessTokenSecretKey)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidIssuer = appSettings.AccessTokenValidIssuer,
            ValidAudience = appSettings.AccessTokenValidAudience
        };
    });
```

With Google things are easy with **GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync** from **using Google.Apis.Auth;**

```
public class GoogleTokenValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
    {
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler;

        public GoogleTokenValidator()
        {
            _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        }

        public bool CanValidateToken => true;

        public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes { get; set; } = TokenValidationParameters.DefaultMaximumTokenSizeInBytes;

        public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken)
        {
            return _tokenHandler.CanReadToken(securityToken);
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
        {
            validatedToken = null;
            var payload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(securityToken, new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()).Result; // here is where I delegate to Google to validate

            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, payload.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, payload.Name),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName, payload.FamilyName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName, payload.GivenName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, payload.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, payload.Subject),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, payload.Issuer),
                };

            try
            {
                var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal();
                principle.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Password"));
                return principle;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;

            }
        }
    }
```

I try to find the same validation pattern for Microsoft Provider but without any success. This is why I'm asking the the SO community to get some answers or some help.

I found Microsoft Graph API and Azure Identity, but it leads me nowhere.

Comment: I understand that you are looking for a way to manually validate the JWT token for the Microsoft provider. Here are some references and docs you could refer to. [Token Validation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#token-validation), [How Do I Manually Validate a JWT Asp.Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50045114/10309381), [Manually validating a JWT token in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824957/10309381), [Manual JWT Validation in .NET Core](https://jfarrell.net/2021/03/09/manual-jwt-validation-in-net-core/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Yesterday, I was thinking Microsoft could have done something like GoogleJsonWebSignature and I was trying to find it. It was a mistake!

I realized I can decode every access token with *System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt* found at https://jwt.io/libraries.

I can then read the tokens this way inside *public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken method* and then write my validation logic :

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(securityToken);
```

Comment: It's really good to know that you have found the solution for your issue and thanks for sharing the solution with us. Could you please try to accept your own answer whenever it is available to mark? It could help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.